# How to get hidden selected objects using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

Can I get a list of the selected objects from Outliner, not from the scene? I want to create a script that unhides the objects selected in the Outliner: the problem is that if I try to grab the objects using `bpy.context.selected_objects` the hidden objects aren't included.

[image]

Comment: It would seem to me that [SpaceOutliner.filter_state](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bpy.types.SpaceOutliner.html) might be relevant, though I'm getting console errors in b2.80 that `"AttributeError: type object 'SpaceOutliner' has no attribute 'filter_state'"`, so I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: I think this is for filter queries, [these ones](https://prnt.sc/pzi2cx) :/

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-2-8-python-hide-unhide-objects/1141228/2

Comment: That would affect *all* hidden objects though, not the ones selected.

Comment: I've been looking through the API and can't find anything relevant. 

The Blender source code contains a `ED_outliner_selected_objects_get()` function in the `ED_outliner.h` library file. Would it be possible to make a C-based addon instead of Python that includes that library file and is able to use it?

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about C and C-based addons: sounds like an overkill for a simple unhide script :/

Comment: It definitely does, though I don't think there's much else you can do if it's not in the API.

Comment: Maybe devs will add this in the future. Thank you for you time!